# export mysql table data to csv file through php..html also get dumped

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

So I was trying to export mysql table to csv file via php. This is the code

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($output, array('User ID', 'User Name', 'Password'));
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'xyz');
    $rows = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM users');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
      fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($con);
  }
?>

<div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Export" name="exp" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Every thing is fine but the html part also gets dumped in the csv file. here is screen shot of the csv
[image: csv output]

Why is that happening? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: separate your code in two different files: `HTML` and `PHP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page continues to load beyond the PHP. Add `exit()` at the end inside the IF statement and it will stop running right there.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($output, array('User ID', 'User Name', 'Password'));
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'xyz');
    $rows = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM users');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
      fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($con);
    exit();
  }
?>

<div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Export" name="exp" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, that does the trick. But why does the html gets written in csv, even if I have closed the file pointer?

Comment: My guess is because the script continues to execute after you close the file pointer. So even though the file pointer is closed, more output exists after that, the HTML. So it just gets tagged onto the end of it.